# first three menu working fine and others not working using

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, scrolltop

I want to change menu background when someone reach that div/section in jquery three section working fine but after that my code is not working i don't know why, its sucking my blood since two days please solve my problem here [its live site](http://staging.moosaconsulting.com/moosaconsulting/)

and here is my jQuery code

```
    var cul_home = $("#home").offset().top;
    var cul_culture = $("#culture").offset().top;
    var cul_work = $("#work").offset().top;
    var cul_services = $("#services").offset().top;
    var cul_careers = $("#careers").offset().top;
    var cul_contactus= $("#contactus").offset().top;
    var cul_locations= $("#locations").offset().top


    var $topscrol = $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($topscrol.scrollTop() > cul_home)
    {   
        $('#menu-item-1726').addClass('cltbck');//home
        $('#menu-item-1715').removeClass('cltbck');//culture
        $('#menu-item-1717').removeClass('worbck');//work
        $('#menu-item-1718').removeClass('serbck');//servicess
        $('#menu-item-1719').removeClass('cerbck');//careers
        $('#menu-item-1720').removeClass('conbck');//contactus
        $('#menu-item-1721').removeClass('locbck');//locations
    }
    else
    {
        $('#menu-item-1726').removeClass('cltbck');//home
    }
    if($topscrol.scrollTop() > cul_culture)
    {
        $('#menu-item-1726').removeClass('cltbck');//home
        $('#menu-item-1715').addClass('cltbck');//culture
        $('#menu-item-1717').removeClass('worbck');//work
        $('#menu-item-1718').removeClass('serbck');//servicess
        $('#menu-item-1719').removeClass('cerbck');//careers
        $('#menu-item-1720').removeClass('conbck');//contactus
        $('#menu-item-1721').removeClass('locbck');//locations
    }
    else
    {
        $('#menu-item-1715').removeClass('cltbck');//home
    }

    if($topscrol.scrollTop() > cul_work)
    {
        $('#menu-item-1726').removeClass('cltbck');//home
        $('#menu-item-1715').removeClass('cltbck');//culture
        $('#menu-item-1717').addClass('worbck');//work
        $('#menu-item-1718').removeClass('serbck');//servicess
        $('#menu-item-1719').removeClass('cerbck');//careers
        $('#menu-item-1720').removeClass('conbck');//contactus
        $('#menu-item-1721').removeClass('locbck');//locations

    }
    else
    {
        $('#menu-item-1717').removeClass('worbck');//home
    }
    if($topscrol.scrollTop() > cul_services)
    {
        $('#menu-item-1726').removeClass('cltbck');//home
        $('#menu-item-1715').removeClass('cltbck');//culture
        $('#menu-item-1717').removeClass('worbck');//work
        $('#menu-item-1718').addClass('serbck');//servicess
        $('#menu-item-1719').removeClass('cerbck');//careers
        $('#menu-item-1720').removeClass('conbck');//contactus
        $('#menu-item-1721').removeClass('locbck');//locations

    }
    else
    {
        $('#menu-item-1718').removeClass('serbck');//home
    }
    if($topscrol.scrollTop() > cul_careers)
    {
        $('#menu-item-1726').removeClass('cltbck');//home
        $('#menu-item-1715').removeClass('cltbck');//culture
        $('#menu-item-1717').removeClass('worbck');//work
        $('#menu-item-1718').removeClass('serbck');//servicess
        $('#menu-item-1719').addClass('cerbck');//careers
        $('#menu-item-1720').removeClass('conbck');//contactus
        $('#menu-item-1721').removeClass('locbck');//locations

    }
    else
    {
         $('#menu-item-1719').removeClass('cerbck');//home
    }

    if($topscrol.scrollTop() > cul_contactus)
    {
        $('#menu-item-1726').removeClass('cltbck');//home
        $('#menu-item-1715').removeClass('cltbck');//culture
        $('#menu-item-1717').removeClass('worbck');//work
        $('#menu-item-1718').removeClass('serbck');//servicess
        $('#menu-item-1719').removeClass('cerbck');//careers
        $('#menu-item-1720').addClass('conbck');//contactus
        $('#menu-item-1721').removeClass('locbck');//locations

    }
    else
    {
        $('#menu-item-1720').removeClass('conbck');//contactus
    }

    if($topscrol.scrollTop() > cul_locations)
    {
        $('#menu-item-1726').removeClass('cltbck');//home
        $('#menu-item-1715').removeClass('cltbck');//culture
        $('#menu-item-1717').removeClass('worbck');//work
        $('#menu-item-1718').removeClass('serbck');//servicess
        $('#menu-item-1719').removeClass('cerbck');//careers
        $('#menu-item-1720').removeClass('conbck');//contactus
        $('#menu-item-1721').addClass('locbck');//locations

    }
    else
    {
        $('#menu-item-1721').removeClass('locbck');//locations
    }

});
```

Comment: you want to highlight current section on scroll?

Comment: yes like this site http://www.vaynermedia.com/

Comment: To implement this you must set you section height according to screen height as you see in vaynermedia.com all section occupy full screen height.

Comment: i am trying to solve this since two days but i don't know why its not working  can you solve this or tell me the alternative solution

Comment: @Komalkhan
1. First, print the scroll positions fr debugging:
`console.log();
console.log( $("#home").offset().top + "     " + cul_home);
console.log( $("#culture").offset().top + "     " + cul_culture);
console.log( $("#work").offset().top + "     " + cul_work);
console.log( $("#services").offset().top + "     " + cul_services);
console.log( $("#careers").offset().top + "     " + cul_careers);
console.log( $("#contactus").offset().top + "     " + cul_contactus);
console.log( $("#locations").offset().top + "     " + cul_locations);
console.log( "****************");
console.log();`

Comment: @Komalkhan 
2. THen put some `console.log()` statements in various if conditions too.

3. Instead of ` if($topscrol.scrollTop() > cul_culture)` your code should be like:  `if($topscrol.scrollTop() > cul_culture && $topscrol.scrollTop() > cul_work)`

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following plugin to solve your scrolling problem it also helps to reduce line of code and improve performance.

1- http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

OR

2- https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/scrolling-nav/
(study its code)

**Note:**
Highly Recommended Bootstrap ScrollSpy (Simple and easy implementation)
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_scrollspy.asp

Hope this helps!